# Running Log Date Format Changing Is Not Working

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

My Log Format :

```
INFO  2018-10-12T09:17:24,530 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) [T11.java][log:248] - [11:11:11]  [RHAZCLPassthroughMessage]
INFO  2018-10-12T09:17:24,532 (TXTHREAD/dev/ttyS1) [T11.java][log:248] - [00:00:00]:   [RHAStatusResponse]
WARN  2018-10-12T09:17:24,536 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) [T12.java][handlePassthrough:278] - RHAZCLPassthroughMessage SN:30 
INFO  2018-10-12T09:17:24,709 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) [T11.java][log:248]  [RHAZCLPassthroughMessage]
INFO  2018-10-12T09:17:24,711 (TXTHREAD/dev/ttyS1) [T11.java][log:248] - [00:00:00]:  [RHAStatusResponse]
WARN  2018-10-12T09:17:24,718 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) [T12.java][handlePassthrough:278] - RHAZCLPassthroughMessage SN:30 
INFO  2018-10-12T09:17:25,991 (OkHttp https://fhk.com/...) [APICallback.java][onResponse:90] - Code: 204, Service: collector-staging
```

My Script to get past hour log

```
date1=$(date -d"now 1 hour ago" "+%FT%T"000"") date2=$(date -d"now 1 hour ago" "+%d") awk -v Date1="$date1" -v Date2="$date2" '{ if ($2 > Date1 && $2 >= Date2) print $2}' /var/log/log.log
```

But here all the logs are getting printed? Any thing is wrong in the script? 
So here I need only past one hour log.

Comment: both variables having `1 hour ago`? Or 1 should be current date and other should be `1 hour ago`? Please confirm.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  one is date and another is time before one hour

Comment: your date format are not the same as the one in the log so string compare badly (not like you expect)

Comment: So you need logs to be printed before 1 hour of current date, could you please confirm the same?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu : So how can i format over here for `2` nd position. Which is in single format ?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes! I need the same as you mentioned !

Comment: @NeronLeVelu This is not printing any log on my output

Comment: adapting the hour from your log, it works here. Add a `print "Lower:[" Lower "]"` in the end of BEGIN section to see the string you compare with

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: Thanks! Working Perfect

Comment: A few more comments: in the declaration of `date1` you forgot the <comma> in front of `000`. This could mess up your sorting!

Comment: So if you would have tested this where `date1` equals `2018-10-12T09:17:24` you will always get true for the `$2 > date1` due to the missing comma, furthermore, `date2` would then represent the number `12` and thus your second statement is again always true because of ascii sorting `20` (comming from `2018`) is bigger then `12`. This statement will be false if you enter date `21`. Also it is very hard for us to judge if you present us code with something like `now - 1 hour`. If we test this 2 hours appart, we have different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use internal strftime and systime function (GNU version only)

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
      # 1 hour before last hour
      BefHr = 1
      Lower=strftime( "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", systime()-((BefHr + 1)*3600) - 1)
      Upper=strftime( "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", systime()- (BefHr*3600) + 1)
      }
   $2 > Lower && $2 < Upper
   ' /var/log/log.log
```